# Image Processing - Which OpenCV algorithm will fit my needs?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, object-recognition

I started to work on a small hobbyist program recently in the area of image processing, and  I'm kind of a noob with image processing but I'm trying to figure out at least some aspects of it.

What I want to be able to do is separate between objects in an image by their color (preferably in a real-time video feed), and then recognize their color.

I read a little about OpenCV and also about some of the different algorithms.
I even started to work a little with the canny algorithm, but I'm not sure this is the algorithm I should begin with for my need, as it detects edges of objects regardless of their color.

Even if it is the algorithm I should use, what would be the best method to recognize the colors of the objects it marked for me?

I hope I made myself clear enough.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To separate or to make a color transparent (for instance to remove it) is very simple with OpenCV... I posted an answer (see the link below) which should help you (or maybe solve your problem).

**[Here is the code I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681503/making-a-color-completely-transparent-in-opencv/6711100#6711100)**

- Moreover, the answer from Martin Beckett is absolutely right, RGB is not a good color space to evaluate a color, you can use HSV, the hue value in degree tells you the proper color (something you could compare from a wavelength in a light spectrum) while S and V code a sort of intensity (what I say is to simplify in order to explain that in many cases to use Hue to segment color images is enough).

> Even if it is the algorithm I should use, what would be the best
>   method to recognize the colors of the objects it marked for me?

- The type of algorithm you are searching for is called color segmentation... [Here is a tutorial which could help you as well.](http://blog.damiles.com/2010/01/segmentation-object-detection-by-color/)

Welcome to image processing community,

Julien,

Answer (score 5):

Understand colour spaces - RGB is almost always the worst source to do image processing on.

Start with [HSL and HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)

Answer (score 0):

For starter you should learn about image array operation, for example using OpenCV function inRange to filter colors by minimum to maximum color range.  Another option is by splitting multi-channel array (in this case R, G and B) to 3 different single-channel for further examination.  Hope its help